# ValueError: OneVsOneClassifier can not be fit when only one class is present. & sklearn.cross_validation

Tags: python, methods, scikit-learn

1. Am trynna use `OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC()).fit(X[0], y)` and it raise an Error from title of my question. `X = [[35   0   182148   0   13   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   60  0]], y = [0]`
   How can I fix it?
2. If I use  `cross_validate.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)` am getting an Error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'`. I printed before it `from sklearn import *` and tried import this method with `from sklearn import cross_validation` but it all raise a one error - AttributeError. How can I fix it?

Comment: module cross_validation from sklearn.model_selection does not have a train_test_split function. You are majorly confused here. You need to use model_selection.train_test_split()  as train_test_split is in the model_selection module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use OneVsOneClassifier which as stated in [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html) is a multiclass classifier. In simple terms, you should have more than one class to make meaning of this classifier. What are you trying to achieve here? If you want a simple classifier that does not require multiclass data, you can probably simply use LinearSVC() (as you are already using that) or some other classifier like Naive Bayes etc. and not OneVsOneClassifier.

Also, you have imported all the modules from sklearn. You are getting confused as to what method is from what module. For eg.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_validate
```

This means that `train_test_split` and `cross_validate` functions are inside model_selection module. If, however, you want to import everything from sklearn, then you should use module name and dot operator to get the function like:

```
from sklearn import *
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, ...other params)
```

Comment: Ty u so much, bro

Comment: So, can you say me where my mark with 'LinearSVC().fit(X, y)' in 'fit'? I can't find info for fix it. If you can help m do it please